# Is it possible to debug a specific Trigger in Zabbix?

Tags: triggers, monitoring, zabbix

I have created a Trigger with a not so straight forward expression. This trigger keeps on being triggered even when it shouldn't. I would like to debug it and see how the values add up. I tried to increase Zabbix log level, the result as an overwhelming amount of data which I couldn't even grep or use regex to find my trigger. (The logs kept rotating too quickly)

So is it possible to debug a specific trigger only?

Comment: Try http://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/action_simulator (if you have supported version) and try tune your Zabbix log config, so the logs wont be rotated so quickly).

Answer (score 1):

- There's a trigger testing feature in the UI.
- Correlate values in item history with the moment the trigger fired and try to go through the ways the trigger evaluated.
- Post the exact expression and what values make it fire in an unexpected fashion.